# Rxjs - How to call two httpService after combinelatest?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I don't know if it's the better solution but I need a function that subscribes to two ngrx selectors and use it as parameters for two http services and I used combineLatest:

```
  combineLatest([this.selectedCompany$, this.account$]).subscribe(res => {
  this.idCompany = res[0]!.id;
  this.account = res[1];
  this.getDashboardCardService(this.account!.id.toString(), this.idCompany.toString(), 'time');
  this.getavailableSpaceService(this.idCompany).subscribe(res => {
      this.space = res;
  })

}).unsubscribe();
```

I use combineLatest to subscribe to two ngrx selectors and in subscribe I need to use these values for doing two http calls, getDashboardCard and available. It works but I don't like it...which is the better solution for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In short, You should make `.pipe(` after `combineLatest`and inside that `pipe` use for example `switchMap` to be able to call another service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this to get you headed the right direction?

Here I use a higher order observable operator (`concatMap`);

```js
combineLatest([this.selectedCompany$, this.account$]).pipe(
  concatMap(([company, account]) => forkJoin([
    this.getDashboardCardService(
      account!.id.toString(), 
      company!.id.toString(), 
      'time'
    ),
    this.getavailableSpaceService(company!.id)
  ]))
).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
  this.space = res2;
});
```